# PHPSECLIB generate PKCS12 without openssl?

Tags: php, phpseclib

Quick question: is it possible to export a cert / key pair in PHPSECLIB directly to PKCS12 format without using OpenSSL as an intermediary? I am trying to write code without requiring any binary PHP extensions on the server and this is the last step I have not been able to do natively. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at present, unfortunately.